# dominating set: NP-hard on graphs without cycles of length 4 and shorter?

Tags: graph-theory

does anyone know whether the problem Dominating Set is still NP-hard on graphs without "triangles" and "rectangles", i.e., graphs without cycles of length 4 or 3?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried replacing every edge by a path 4 edges long?  The resulting graph has no cycles of length $<12$ and I think its domination number will be closely related to the original's.